# StroyBoard View - Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2, storyboard

when I was working with **story board** i got a display like below.

[image]

Why is that?

how can i convert it to previews view?

Thanks alot

Comment: .xib files are actually xml files.. I guess that is what you are seeing here..

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how it could have happened to you, but to view it as an Interface Builder storyboard again, follow these steps:

1. Close the file.
2. Right-click or Control-click on the file in the left pane.
3. In the context menu, choose **Open As > Interface Builder – iOS Storyboard**.

Comment: This happens to me about once a day in Xcode 4.2. I usually just restart Xcode. I'll try this next time.

Comment: @Mark Adams: Does it happen at random? I've not encountered this in Xcode 4 yet, but I recall it happening in Xcode 3, once or twice.

Comment: Completely random. I've yet to be able to reproduce.